# Step back in directories with nodejs path module

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, fs

How to get this file in fs:

```
'../dist/index.js'
```

i tried this:

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.js')
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```js
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/index.js'))
```

Comment: I use it like `__dirname + '/../dist/index.js'` in my project, and it works.

Comment: Could you provide directory structure? And what kind of error comes up?

Answer (score 7):

This will work on all OS

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.js'));
```